# Question about completely metrizable spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

We say a metric space X is completely metrizable if there a metric that induces its usual topology and X with that metric is complete.
I´ve seen, for example, that (0,1) is completely metrizable and the argument usually is "it is homeomorphic to a complete space".

But is it true that if X, Y are metric spaces, Y with complete with the metric $d_{Y}$ and $f$ homeomorhism between X and Y, then there is a metric in X which turns the space into a complete one?

My thoughts were on the metric $d_{X}(x,y)=d_{Y}(f(x),f(y))$. But I don´t see why X has to be complete with this?

I would really apreciate any help on this, thank you in advance!

Comment: $X$ with metric $d_X$ is complete, yes. This is actually very simple, if $x_n$ is a $d_X$-Cauchy sequence then $f(x_n)$ converges to some point $f(x)$, so $x_n$ converges to $x$

Comment: ohhh right, I was forgeting I had to consider cauchy with respect to my new metric $d_{X}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as @Jakobian was saying, if $x_{n}$ in $X$ is a cauchy sequence with respect to the metric $d_{X}$, $d_{X}(x,y)=d_{Y}(f(x),f(y))$, then $f(x_{n})$ would be cauchy in the complete metric space $Y$!  So, it converges to some point y in $Y$, that's of the form $f(x)$ for some $x\in X$. As $f^{-1}$ is continuous and these are metric spaces, $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x)$ implies $(f^{-1}of)(x_{n}) \rightarrow (f^{-1}of)(x)$ that is: $x_{n} \rightarrow x$.

This proves every cauchy sequence converges, therefore, $X$ is complete!